# Ubuntu 18.04 File manager app hard to read columns

Tags: 18.04, files

After upgrading to 18.04, I noticed that when I opened the Files app, the columns such as Size and Modified are displayed with a gray font that's hard to read sometimes. Is there a way to darken these letters to normal black?

Comment: Sounds like a theming issue, try switching your "applications theme" (GTK+).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they can be changed to black color.

but the simply way is to try some GTK+ themes from gnome-look.org website or from the default themes that comes out of the box in Ubuntu 18.04.

I have changed the color to black with the default theme "Radiance" that came up with Ubuntu 18.04 in the below way.

in order to change it. First you need to know which GTK+ theme is being used. to know that open `Gnome-Tweaks` application. if not yet installed, install it by the below command `sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` or simply search in Ubuntu Software as "gnome tweaks".

[image]

Open Gnome Tweaks, look for the name of theme under Appearane-Themes-Applications

[image]

in my case i selected "Radiance" as my GTK+ theme, so when i open file manager, it looks like this.

[image]

now open the folder `sudo nautilus /usr/share/themes/`
look for the folder "Radiance" Open it and find the file `nautilus.css` in sub folder of "gtk-3.20" under "apps" folder.

[image]

Open the file nautilus.css and find the section at the top of the page

```
nautilus-desktop-window.background:backdrop,
.nautilus-desktop-window.background:backdrop {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.nautilus-canvas-item {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.nautilus-canvas-item.dim-label,
.nautilus-list-dim-label {
    color: mix (@theme_fg_color, @theme_bg_color, 0.50);
}

.nautilus-canvas-item.dim-label:selected,
.nautilus-list-dim-label:selected {
    color: mix (@theme_selected_fg_color, @theme_selected_bg_color, 0.20);
```

and change it like

```
nautilus-desktop-window.background:backdrop,
.nautilus-desktop-window.background:backdrop {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.nautilus-canvas-item {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.nautilus-canvas-item.dim-label,
.nautilus-list-dim-label {
    color: #000000; #here you can put any color you want
}

.nautilus-canvas-item.dim-label:selected,
.nautilus-list-dim-label:selected {
    color: #000000; #here you can put any color you want
```

Save the file and Close.
Logout or Reboot to see the change.

[image]

Comment: My [theme_name].css file contains
`@import url("resource:///com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru/3.20/gtk.css");`
What now?